# Проблемы с time.h

Tags: c, библиотеки, время

Доброго времени суток! Хотел побаловаться с time.h и посмотреть, что в ней есть. При выводе полей структуры tm (описывает календарное время, скрин о содержании прилагаю) получил следующее (см скрин кода и вывода). При перезапуске выдает различные результаты (кроме двух последних полей).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где у меня ошибка. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Непонятно в чём вопрос. Ну выводите вы какой-то мусор, мусор и получаете. Всё правильно. Или вы считаете, что одного объявления переменной типа `tm` достаточно, чтобы её поля заполнились правильными значениями? Я уж не говорю о работе с инкрементом указателя - что это вообще было?

Comment: Добавьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код у Вас не работает т.к. Вы только объявили структуру `my`, но не инициализировали ее. У ее полей нет значений, по-этому и выводится мусор из выделенной для нее памяти.

Вот рабочий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    time_t t         = time(NULL);
    struct tm * my = localtime(&t);

    printf("tm_sec   : %i\n"
           "tm_min   : %i\n"
           "tm_hour  : %i\n"
           "tm_mday  : %i\n"
           "tm_mon   : %i\n"
           "tm_year  : %i\n"
           "tm_wday  : %i\n"
           "tm_yday  : %i\n"
           "tm_isdst : %i\n",
           my->tm_sec,
           my->tm_min,
           my->tm_hour,
           my->tm_mday,
           my->tm_mon,
           my->tm_year,
           my->tm_wday,
           my->tm_yday,
           my->tm_isdst);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, кратко и понятно, а самое главное - помогло :)

Answer (score 2):

Попробую дать ответ на простом языке...

Дело не в `time.h`.

Когда вы объявляете любую переменную - хоть простейший `int i` - вы по сути говорите "мне нужен кусок памяти, в котором я буду хранить значение типа `int` и который буду называть `i`". Это место вам выделяется. Но для локальных переменных (объявленных в функции) для эффективности компилятор просто выделяет память *и все* - он не дает ей никакого значения.

Когда вы просто описали свою переменную, в которой - когда-нибудь! - будет храниться какое-то время - все, что делается - выделяется кусок памяти в стеке. Теперь ваше дело - сказать, чем ее заполнить. Так же, как прежде чем использовать ту же `int i`, ей надо присвоить какое-то значение (иначе в ней будет что-то случайное, оставшееся в памяти от других переменных или даже других программ.

Как заполнить - вопрос другой, в `time.h` описаны соответствующие функции (а равно во множестве книг, справочников и т.д.).

Еще дам **очень настоятельный** совет - не надо засовывать в вопрос картинки. Неужели так сложно скопировать текст? Сложнее, чем снимать копию экрана? :)